# InvalidArgumentException in Fileviewfinder.php line 137

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I got this error out of nowhere. 
Been working on for a while and suddenly this happened.
My screenshots are:-
the error:-
[image]
controller:-
[image]

Routes:-
[image]

Must be a simple solution, but I can't find it.
I am using laravel 5.3

Comment: `view('/');` does what?

Comment: Your error: `view('/');` I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think your about file code is incorrect because your about.blade.php under "cards" folder so replace your code:

```
return view('about');
```

to

```
return view('cards.about');
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: but cards.blade.php is out of the cards folder. And cards folder is empty.